# Not found Page with master page in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

i created a master page then i created a web form with master page. Finally, i run the project and it runs the admin/Books url again while it has to run Views/Admin/Books.aspx . That leads to 404 not found error, am I missing something here?
Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AdminMaster.master.cs" Inherits="BookWebApp.Views.Admin.AdminMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../../Assets/Lib/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 bg-teal">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <img src="../../Assets/Images/Book.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <h4>
                            Books
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9 ">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MyContent" runat="server">
        
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web form with master page i create:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Admin/AdminMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Books.aspx.cs" Inherits="BookWebApp.Views.Admin.Books" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MyContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

The Directory structure :

```
Views
 Admin
  AdminMaster.Master
  Books.aspx
 Login.aspx
```

why does it happen like this